# How to find all homomorphisms from SU(2) to U(1)

Tags: lie-groups

How to find all such non-trivial homomorphisms? At the Lie algebra level, should it just be a projection to the one-dimensional sub-space arbitrarily singled out? Could there be other Lie algebra homomorphisms? I searched on-line but failed to find anything useful. And is there a method to find them for general SU(n)? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such homomorphism. The only proper normal subgroup of $SU(2)$ is it's center $Z=\{\pm 1\}$, and that cannot be the kernel of a homomorphism to $U(1)$ since $SU(2)/Z=SO(3)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Simplicity is what I missed. Thank you!